# Magento Template Tag Output (storeDirective)

Tags: url, module

I'm adding a textearea to the **Catalog** > **Manage Categories** > **General Information** tab in which I can put additional description for the category page. In the frontend this needs to appear at the bottom of the category, below the category collection. I want to do this in the form of a custom module and so far everything works, except for one tiny little issue.

I want to use **Magento Template Tags** in the backend textarea, like the `{{store direct_url=''}}` storeDirective, but this doesn't work in the frontend. Somehow the output for those tags is not correct. It gives `www.domain.com/category/%7B%7Bstore direct_url''%7D%7D`

I've read that the value comes from the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter` class and therefore I have created a `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Template_Filter` class which contains

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Template_Filter extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter
{
}
```

But this doesn't work. I'm stuck now and would really appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding Class `Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper_Output` to my module with the following content:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Helper_Output extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output
{
    public function categoryAttribute($category, $attributeHtml, $attributeName)
    {
        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isUrlDirectivesParsingAllowed()) {
            $attributeHtml = $this->_getTemplateProcessor()->filter($attributeHtml);
        }
        $attributeHtml = $this->process('categoryAttribute', $attributeHtml, array(
            'category'  => $category,
            'attribute' => $attributeName
        ));
        return $attributeHtml;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to pass the variable through the filter method in the template:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
echo $processor->filter($_categoryDescription);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try and see how this works out.